# Controlling ICS access with Windows Firewall (windows7)

Tags: windows-7, firewall, connection-sharing

I'm looking for links to documentation or clues on how to add rules to windows firewall to deny all access to internet from computers connected via ICS and then allow only a minimal set of TCP ports.

The equivalent as it were, of adding rules to iptables FORWARD on linux. 
I ask because it doesn't work as one might expect, so please, answers based on experience, not speculation.

Some context:

I'm sharing a limited bandwidth 3G connection via ICS using windows7 built-in SoftAP. This is to give access to an android wifi device. However, I want to control what the android device can do.

Searching for answers about windows firewall and ICS is hampered by the amount of results concerning the firewall/ICS combined service. Also, in general, I struggle to understand the windows firewall logic from an iptables point of view. There seems to be no concept of rule order. I tried making rules that apply to the ICS service. I tried using the same and different profiles on both the SoftAP adapter and the 3G connection. In general, ICS seems to bypass most Firewall rules.

Comment: What is ICS? The tag reads ".ics is the iCalendar file format, an open standard for storing calendars.". I don't think you mean that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting "outbound" rules in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.  Under the ports section you can specify what ports you want to open -- just make sure that you put the ip address of the android device in the "remote IP" section of the rule scope.

For more clarity on how the firewall prioritizes rules (and how to override a blocking rule) see this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd421709(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving an old post, but in case someone is still searching for this:

In Windows 7 to 10, Windows Firewall only fitlers Local connections (Inbound and Outbound are equivalent to INPUT and OUPUT in iptables.
Networks using ICS or Bridging completly bypass these rules.

In ICS, iptables' FORWARD can be accomplished in the connection sharing settings:
http://www.utilizewindows.com/internet-connection-sharing-ics-configuration-in-windows-7/

Iptables' PREROUTING and POSTROUTING cannot be accomplished in Windows with official Microsoft packages, at least that I know of.

**However:**

Recently I wanted to protect my computer & network from an "potentially unsecure" server connected through ICS (E.g.: RaspberryPi Webserver).
I accomplished it by NOT using ICS/bridging, and instead creating a network forwarding only the service I want:

- Configured static IPs between the PC's 2nd NIC and raspberry.
- Activated tcpip router in every PC's NIC.
  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962461.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
- Configured portproxy (port forwarding) from "public IP":80 to internal 
  raspberry PI:80
- Configured the PC firewall to block all (new) connections coming from the raspberry pi (to protect the PC from a hacked raspberry)
- Made it reapply in every boot, which for some reason was not doing it correctly. What solved was, at boot, running a .bat that makes "netsh interface portproxy reset" + "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4  .... "

Note: No connections whatsoever will be accepted from the raspberryPi, only going to it from your PC or through the port you forward. This also means the Raspberry Pi won't have an internet connection.